# Is there a way to turn Duplifaces (Instansing in version 2.8) into a mesh?

Tags: modeling

I have a mesh that has duplifaces (https://youtu.be/diI8xJ9oo_8) on it and I want to know if there’s a way to make all the duplifaces one mesh so I can edit each part that’s duplicated individually in Belender 2.8 (in previous version solution was shift ctrl-A on the parent object, but now it doesn't work). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In object mode select the parent object, press F3 to access the search menu and type "make instances real".

Or in the menu look for Object>apply>make instances real. (or press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select Make Instances Real)

[image]

Form the [blender 2.8 manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html?highlight=instances%20real#make-instances-real)

> Make Instances Real creates a new object for each instance generated by the selected ones, and removes any direct instancing from those.
>
> In the end, each instance becomes a real object.

Comment: O thanks a lot!